# False positives and false negatives selenium confusing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

How can I avoid false negatives in selenium webdriver and what are the good practices to have a robust code.

I often have errors ***(cannot invoke element)*** with click function.

Comment: Any example of `false positives` and `false negatives` you are facing?

Comment: exemple when i try to check if an element isDisplayed ,sometimes it returns false yet the element isDisplayed .